# Sequel Left Join

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, sequel

My aim is to build a relationship between rooms, people and work shift. So my sequel string looks like this :

```
      x =  DB[:raum].join_table(:left, DB[:platz], :rid => :id)
      .join_table(:left, DB[:patient_behandlungs_link], :platz_id => :id)
      .join_table(:left, DB[:patienten], :id => :patienten_id)
      .join_table(:left, DB[:behandlungsverfahren], :id => :t2__behandlungsverfahren_id)
      .join_table(:left, DB[:dialysezeit], :id => :t2__dialysezeit_id)
      .join_table(:left, DB[:nadeln], :id => :t2__dialysenadel_id)
      .join_table(:left, DB[:dialysatorzugang], :id => :t2__dialysatorzugang_id)
      .where("raumnummer = ?", raumid.to_i)
```

It's working like this but in the resulting table there is also a field for the shift id. In this state it does not differentiate in which workshift the person is working. if i do a foreach and push the values out I get my empty nil fields with no one inside, which I want to, and I get the people which are in room raumid from all workshifts.

If I make a `.filter(:schicht_id => 1)` for example, then I loose my nil values. I need them to assign new people to the empty slots, so I tried `(:schicht_id => 1).or(:schicht_id => nil)` and similar things but I don't get my result, I want

Comment: You code would be much easier to read and to understand when you name your classes and method in English. Ruby's methods names and syntax allow to write very comprehensible code. Unfortunately this doesn't work when you mix different languages, the reader has to switch language context a lot...

Comment: I don't find a `schicht` (=work shift) in your join. So where do you define your filter on `schicht_id`?

Answer (score 0):

I think i blamed sequel for something that is not related to sequel.
[In the image my select box starts showing options from the second value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVSDN.png)

This behavior made me think, something was wrong with my joins and group by instructions.... i now have to figure out why the select box shows me from values form 2-9 and not from 1-9. In the HTML Site Source code all 9 Options are given.
This is strange for me.

sorry for blaming sequel.